# Bash - easy way to compare strings which have different delimiters?

Tags: bash

Is there a better way to check if two strings are equal while ignoring a given delimiter, example:

```
function is_equal() {
    local str1="$1"
    local delim1="$2"
    local str2="$3"
    local delim2="$4"

    IFS=$delim1 read -r -a array1 <<< "$str1"
    IFS=$delim2 read -r -a array2 <<< "$str2"

    if [[ ${#array1[@]} -ne ${#array2[@]} ]]; then
        return 1
    fi

    str1raw=$(IFS='' echo "${array1[*]}")
    str2raw=$(IFS='' echo "${array2[*]}")

    if [ "${str1raw}" != "${str2raw}" ]; then
        return 1
    fi

    return 0
}

is_equal "!etc!daemon!sys.conf" "!" "/etc/daemon/sys.conf" "/"
```

This works but I'd like to not work with arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as it is safe that your strings contain text data, meaning printable chars only, you can use parameter expansion to replace the delimiters by non-printable characters before the comparison. Doing so both string share the same delimiter during the comparison:

```
if [ "${str1//$delim1/\\x01}" = "${str2//$delim2/\\x01}" ] ; then
    echo "strings are equal"
fi
```

I'm using a non-printable character for the delimiter to make sure that the delimiter will not be part of the data itself.

Comment: This is probably safe in practice, but isn't guaranteed to be safe (still upvoting, though).

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm also not *really* happy with this.

Comment: It's a domain-specifc problem: we don't *know* that ASCII 01 can't occur in one of the components. Maybe the first string is `!etc!daemon!why\x01did\x01you\x01pick\x01this\x01name` :)

Comment: Ok, I'll add a sentence telling that the solution can be used for text-data but not for arbitrary binary data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use arrays. Usually, an array is used to store a set of items which might whatever character you would think to separate two items. Here, you have a mutual problem: each string already has a safe delimiter for itself, but that elimiter isn't necessarily safe for the other.

In order to do component-wise comparisons, you need to choose a common delimiter that is safe for both--which takes us back to the problem arrays were introduced to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want avoid working with arrays, you can do this:

```
function is_equal {
    local str1="$1"
    local delim1="$2"
    local str2="$3"
    local delim2="$4"

    diff <( tr -d "$delim1" <<< "$str1" ) \
         <( tr -d "$delim2" <<< "$str2" ) > /dev/null 2>&1 

}
```

It might be slower, but it's shorter and easier to read IMHO.

Comment: When you want `is_equal aa_bb _ aab_b _` to return false, you must change something. When all input strings are oneliners, you can change all delimiters into newlines.

Comment: @WalterA I agree with you, however my answers mimics OP's solution without using arrays. What can be done in that case is instead of deleting the delimiter we could replace it by something else like a null character.